# How to drop an unnamed constraint in DB2 using a script

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table with a constrained on it that I don't know the name of because it is system-generated, and I need to drop that constraint using a script.

Answer (score 2):

Put this in a file myscript.sql:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DROP_CONSTRAINT()
LANGUAGE SQL
CALLED ON NULL INPUT

BEGIN ATOMIC
    declare myconstraint varchar(128);
    declare stmt varchar(2000);

    --- select your constraint using the table and column names it consists of
    set myconstraint = (select constname from syscat.keycoluse where tabname='MYTABLE' and colname='MYCOL') ;
    set stmt = 'alter table mytable drop constraint '|| myconstraint ;

    prepare s1 from stmt;
    execute s1;
END@
```

Call it like this:

```
db2 -td@ -svf "myscript.sql"
db2 "call DROP_CONSTRAINT()"
db2 "drop procedure DROP_CONSTRAINT"
```

Comment: You may want to account for a case where multiple constraints reference the same column...

Comment: You can also do this as a compound SQL statement without having to create a stored procedure.

Comment: @IanBjorhovde: I'd be interested in that, especially if it works in plain JDBC without the db2 command line tool.